# My small code is not working

Tags: php, arrays

At the moment, I'm working on a small script.
I'm new at PHP, I've got a problem
I have a field in database and the field content is like this
`"1","2","3"`
When i put these numbers in array
like this
`$users=array("1","2","3");`
 , my code will work , but when i put these codes in a variable and put variable inside the array like this
`$users=array($amanj);`
 it wont.
Please Help me if possible.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to redesign your database because having `"1","2","3"` is not a good idea if you really need 3 separate values.

But to answer your question, if you need to convert the string `"1","2","3"` to an array, you can do:

```
$users = explode(',', $amanj);
```